# Elastic Load Balancer + Domain setup

Tags: load-balancing, amazon-web-services, cname-record

How do I assign the ELB (Elastic Load Balancer) to my domain. Do I need to do it for the main domain (ie. domain.com) or sub domain (www.domain.com). My registrar is godaddy - how I do it? - What's the most recommended way?

I also later want to redirect traffic from non-www to www (301 redirect via IIS) or vice versa and I need it to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using AWS's Route53 with ELB this isn't a problem to point the `example.com` to an ELB CNAME record. Short of that it has to be done by a service rather than through DNS because  of [RFC 1034](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.txt)  section 3.6.2 paragraph 3 which reads:

> ...  If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no other data should be
>   present; this ensures that the data for a canonical name and its
>   aliases cannot be different.  This rule also insures that a cached
>   CNAME can be used without checking with an authoritative server for
>   other RR types.

In other words it states that you can not have a CNAME RRset with any other RRset and a domain name record requires at a minimum 2 RRsets (SOA & NS) there by making it mutually exclusive with a CNAME RRset.

GoDaddy gets around this by offering domain `Forwarding` on their DomainManager details for the Domain Information. This updates the DNS record for your domain to point to one of their servers and it redirects the web-based domain requests to another URL. I utilize this for several domains that I have hosted with GoDaddy and running behind AWS ELBs. You just point the entry for `www.example.com` to your ELB CNAME RRset and then with the Forwarding in enable it'll be redirected as expected.

To accomplish the same without using GoDaddy, you would have to have a host with a static IP, or EC2 instance with an EIP, running Apache or some other web server that could simply issue a 301 or 302 redirect back to `www.example.com`. I have also found that [EasyDNS](http://easydns.com) also offers a URL forwarding feature the appears to provide the same functionality as GoDaddy's but I have not had a chance to try it out.

Comment: I'm using Amazon Route53 and now try to use interstate53.com to do it. I've set the CNAME to the ELB dns, but I don't know what information to put in the 'Alias' for the non-www domain in the Hosted ID field (See image here: http://picturepush.com/public/6765561). need your help on this